# How to provision a vagrant VM with Chef and and a .rb file filled with instructions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant, chef

I probably got the whole concept wrong: I have a working Vagrant VM with Ubuntu 12.04, on top of it I want to install a few packages and config files. I have them set in Chef, in the path cookbooks/my_project/recipes I have a vagrant-dev.rb file with all the instructions. Now my Vagrant config in Vagrantfile must be the problem here:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks/my_project/recipes"
    chef.add_recipe "vagrant-dev.rb"
end
```

and when I load the VM I get

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook vagrant-dev.rb not found.
```

I tried without the .rb at the end. I guess it's a completely different matter and I'm not using it the correct way. But after searching I couldn't find anything that explained how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the /my_project/recipes from cookbooks_path.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, please be aware 1 line answers a commonly frowned upon :( please consider elaborating on your answer